# How to write into RabbitMQ from Azure databricks?

Tags: azure, pyspark, rabbitmq, azure-databricks

I am currently learning to use RabbitMQ. I am trying to publish a message to RabbitMQ from Azure Databricks using pyspark. Any idea about how would that be achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, RabbitMQ is not supported as a source in Azure Databricks.

Azure Databricks - [Streaming Data Sources and Sinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/data-sources?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fazure-databricks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

Structured Streaming has built-in support for a number of streaming data sources and sinks (for example, files and Kafka) and programmatic interfaces that allow you to specify arbitrary data writers.

- Apache Kafka
- Azure Event Hubs
- Delta Lake Tables
- Read and Write Streaming Avro Data with DataFrames
- Write to Arbitrary Data Sinks
- Optimized Azure Blob Storage File Source with Azure Queue Storage

As per my research, I have found a third-party tool named "**Panoply**" which [integrate Databricks and RabbitMQ using Panoply](https://panoply.io/integrations/databricks/rabbitmq/).

Hope this helps.